# What pattern should I use to catch apache vhost items in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to catch the following in a logstash grok command:

```
    www.example.com:443 41.177.65.213 - - [03/Sep/2016:15:05:49 +0200] "GET 
/feed/history?symbol=GGI&resolution=D&from=1472043948&to=1472907948 
HTTP/1.1" 200 1337 "https://www.example.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; 
x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 
Safari/537.36"
```

I have tried:

```
grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:vhost}\:%{NUMBER:port} %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed it:

```
    grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:vhost}:%{NUMBER:port} %
{IPORHOST:clientip} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] (?:%{WORD:verb} %
{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest}) %
{QS:agent}" }
        }
```

A bit much, I know. I used this [github patterns resource](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns)